# How would you solve this problem using log?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I have this equation and I want to find the possible values of $n$. So how would you solve this using logarithms?

$10n^2 = 2^n$

Comment: In order to get a good help, it is important to provide your own thoughts for the question.

Comment: You can express the solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Alternatively, if you want to avoid this then you can solve this numerically. For example, you can use the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).

Comment: there are three Solutions expressed by the Lambert-W function

Comment: You say you have two equations.  I see only one.

Comment: One solution is smaller then $10$ since $10\cdot 10^2=1000$ and $2^n=1024$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to find the solution of this equation using logarithm.

You can find the roots with some numerical method or using the [Lambert W function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10x%5E2%3D2%5Ex). If you want a simple estimate of the roots tha you can sketch the graphs of the functions

$y =10n^2$ and $y=2^n$ ( it is easy)

and  search the common points. You see immediately that there is a negative solution $x_1<0$ and a positive solution $0<x_2<1$ because $10\cdot 1^2 > 2^1$. Since we have $2^{10} < 10\cdot 10^2$ there is also another solution $1<x_3<10$ (and you can  easily restrict the interval to $9<x_3<10$).